# How to add scrolling to table-row-group body of css based table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create this:

[image]

I used the `display: table` property and `table-header-group`, `table-row-group`, `table-row`, `table-cell` css properties instead of using table tags.

When I add `overflow-y: scroll` to `table-row-group` nothing changes, and it activates the scroll of the card.

I removed the overflow of the card and still can't make the body of the table to scroll.

Why can't you do it with `table-row-group`?

I created a dummy [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p3hd0nxu/), it looks differently but works the same, you can see the text overflowing outside.

Comment: First off, why don't you put this data into a table? That's what they're for...displaying tabular data.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You're required to show your code _here_.

Comment: @isherwood I provided a JsFiddle, the code is too long for the example to be pasted here.

Comment: The code required to demonstrate the problem you're facing is almost certainly not too long. Please read that page. Your question will be closed by the community otherwise.

Comment: The code is 275 lines of code excluding the SCSS code, in purpose to demonstrate the over lapping of the elements. How is this not too long? I'll ask again, what could be better than a runnable JSFiddle that explains my issue properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw your code.
The problem is that the overflow-y style must be added to **.card** class not **.body** class. It's because you want to scroll on the div with **.card** class.
You can see the corrected style below.

```css
.card {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  
    padding: 16px;
  
    .container {
      width: 100%;
      display: table;
      border-spacing: 8px;
      border-collapse: collapse;
  
      .header {
        color: var(--neutrals-70);
        display: table-header-group;
  
        .row {
          display: table-row;
          border-bottom: solid 1px var(--neutrals-40);
  
          .cell {
            display: table-cell;
            padding: 16px 0;
  
            .cell-container {
              width: 100%;
              display: flex;
              justify-content: center;
              align-items: center;
            }
          }
        }
      }
  
      .body {
        color: var(--neutrals-70);
        display: table-row-group;
        height: 10px;
  
        .row {
          display: table-row;
          vertical-align: center;
  
          .cell {
            display: table-cell;
            border-spacing: 0;
            padding: 4px 0;
            vertical-align: middle;
  
            .cell-container {
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              display: flex;
              align-items: center;
            }
          }
        }
  
      }
  
    }
  
 }
```

Comment: Hi thank you, but as I said I want the body of the table to be scrollable, not the card. the header of the table must be sticky.

Comment: I suggest you to use table tag. You can see [here](https://launchhubstudio.com/blog/sticky-table-headers#:~:text=Currently%2C) an example of using this tag with sticky header. I think it would be better and easier than using div tag.